# Can we find four reals $x,y,a,b$ such that $z=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the quantity:

$$z=(2^{p}-1)β^{2^{p-2}}k-β^{2^{p-1}}>0$$ where $p$ is a prime, $k$ is a natural number and $β$ is a real number, i.e., $β=√3+2$. My question is: Can we find four reals $x,y,a,b$ such that:

$$z=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$$

Comment: As long as $z$ isn't negative...

Comment: @Macavity: Yes, $z$ is positive.

Comment: Then why not $x=\sqrt z, a=y=b=0$?

Comment: @Macavity: Yes, but I am seeking for $x,y$ non zero.

Comment: Why don't you put all conditions in the question. Ok then take same $x,a$ and $y=b=1$. There are a whole host of possibilities.

Comment: @DER: But the problem is just as trivial even if you require them to be nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is $(p,β,k,x,a,y,b)=(3,1,1,1+2^{1/2},1,6,4)$.

And thus 4 reals have been found.